# Custom Unsubscribe CloudPage Not working in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am working on a custom unsubscribe page that will allow customers to unsubscribe from an email. I have a custom CloudPage created (MAIN page) with two CTAs YES and NO. When customer clicks on the 'YES' button they will be redirected to the 'YES' page which confirms that they are unsubscribed.

The unsubscribe preferences needs to update the Contact in Sales Cloud and also All Subscribers in MC. Also I need to log any error on a DE.

The issue I have is that the 'YES' page is not rendering and I'm getting Error 500. I tried using error trycatch function but no error message is displayed. I also tried the to pass hardcoded values, view the page on incognito page but it's not working.
The 'NO' page is simple confirmation message so no values are passed there.

I have it working once but the values I was trying to update in Sales Cloud were not updated.

Here is the AMPscript I use on the 'MAIN' page to capture the ContactID and the JobID:

```ampscript
%%[
var @contactId, @jobid
SET @contactId = QueryParameter("cid")
SET @jobid = QueryParameter("jobid")
]%%
```

Here is the example of the CloudPage URLs I'm passing.

**YES Page** [Page ID example 1234] >>> %%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1234, 'cid2', @contactId, 'jobid', @jobid))=%%

**NO Page** [Page ID example 5678] >>> %%=CloudPagesURL('5678')=%%

Here is the AMPscript I use on the 'YES' page (I tried two approaches but non of them are working):

Example 1:

```ampscript
%%[

var @currentTime, @formattedUTCDate, @contactID, @jobID, @updateStatus, @reason, @logUnsubEvent, @error

/* Set current time */
SET @currentTime = DateAdd(Now(), 6, "H")
SET @formattedUTCDate = Format(@currentTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", "Date")

/* Update Sales Cloud and MC Contact preferences */
set @contactID = QueryParameter("cid")
set @jobID = QueryParameter("jobid")
set @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    "Contact", 
    @contactID, 
    "EmailOptIn__c", 
    "False",
    "EmailConsentSource__c",
    "Preference Center",
    "EmailConsentCaptureDate__c",
    @formattedUTCDate
)

if @updateStatus == 1 then
    set @reason = "Unsubscribed via Email"
    set @logUnsubEvent = LogUnsubEvent(@jobID, @contactID, @reason)
else
    set @error = "Error updating Salesforce Object"
    InsertData("Unsubscribe Log DE", "ContactID", @contactID, "Email", @email, "Date", Now(), "Errored", "True", "ErrorMessage", @error)
endif
]%%
```

Example 2:

```ampscript
%%[
/* 1. Fetch query parameters from MAIN Unsub page.*/
var @contactId, @JobID, @currentTime, @formattedUTCDate

set @contactId = QueryParameter("cid2")
set @JobID = QueryParameter("jobid")
set @currentTime = DateAdd(Now(), 6, "H")
set @formattedUTCDate = Format(@currentTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", "Date")

var @dataExtension, @sfObject, @AccountId

SET @dataExtension = 'ACCOUNT_SALESFORCE_01'
SET @sfObject = 'Account'
SET @AccountId = Lookup("ACCOUNT_SALESFORCE_01", "Id", "PersonContactID", @contactId)

/* 2. Update Sales Cloud data */

var @updateStatus

IF @sfObject == "Account" THEN
set @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    "Account", @AccountId, 
    "EmailOptIn__c", "False",
    "EmailConsentSource__c", "MC Unsubscribe Page",
    "EmailConsentCaptureDate__c", @formattedUTCDate
)
set @updateStatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    "Contact", @contactID,  
    "EmailOptIn__c", "False",
    "EmailConsentSource__c", "MC Unsubscribe Page",
    "EmailConsentCaptureDate__c", @formattedUTCDate
)
else
set @error = "Error updating Salesforce Object"
    InsertData("Unsubscribe Log DE", "ContactID", @contactID, "Email", @email, "Date", Now(), "Errored", "True", "ErrorMessage", @error)
ENDIF

]%%
```

Example of the email code for the unsubscribe page:

```ampscript
%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%
   %%profile_center_url%%
%%[endif]%%
%%[
    VAR @ContactId
    SET @ContactId = AttributeValue("Contact:ID")  
 ]%%                        
You can <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(3449, 'cid1', @ContactId))=%%" alias="Manage Preferences" title="Manage Preferences">unsubscribe if you no longer wish to receive this email</a>.
```

Comment: I'd comment out all of your UpdateSingleSalesforceObject functions and output the name/value pairs for debugging.  Those functions are fragile and I see you've already dealt with the date format gotcha.  I suspect the debugging output will indicate a missing value or a datatype mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @AdamSpriggs Do you mean to try the values one by one within the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject functions? I was expecting the try catch function to work too but it doesn't show any errors only error 500.